# FirebaseのSessionIDの安全性

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Vue.jsとFirebaseで開発したSPAの安全性を確認しています。
OWASP ZAPという診断ツールで脆弱性チェックをしていたところ、
URLにセッションIDが含まれている旨の警告がでました。

下記のURLです（POSTメソッド）。
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?database=projects%2Fproject-name%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&gsessionid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&SID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&RID=xxxxx&AID=x&zx=xxxxxx&t=1x
※一部ダミーに差し替えています

一般的にセッションIDはURLに含むべきではないと思っておりましたが、
これは安全なのでしょうか？何らかの対策が必要なのでしょうか？

Googleの開発したサービスなので信用していたのですが、不安になりました。

Comment: 質問に書かれているリンク(URL)をクリックすると「400. That’s an error.」の画面が出ました。
URLが正しいか確認してください。正しくない場合にはURLを修正してください。

Comment: Fumu様 URLは実際のものではなく、プロジェクト名やSセッションIDをダミーのものに差し替えています。